# how to validate cake php 3 hashed genereted password using other framework?

Tags: php, laravel, cakephp

I have SQL and i want to rebuild application using laravel, while old same  application in cake php 3 ,i am facing issue in user login. I tried simply checking in where cluase in laravel:

```
    if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> "XXXX@gmail.com",'password'=> "XXXX"])){
        echo "Success";
     }else{
        echo "Not Success";
     }
    OR

     $user = User::where('email', '=', 'XXXX@gmail.com')->first();
    if ($user && Hash::check("XXXX", $user->password)) {
      echo "Valid Password ";
    } else {
       echo "Invalid password";
    }
```

But it didn't work for me is there any approach to solve this issue.

Please help.

Comment: You simply use the same underlying code that your app / CakePHP uses. So start by checking how your CakePHP app is hashing the passwords.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `CakePHP`'s `DefaultPasswordHasher` class, you should be able to do the following:

```
$hash = '$2y$10$nPZHimhuTrbOkISL57khoenU/9rx9/P794Un9p3fhwXq6cWJBH6zS';
var_dump(password_verify('abc', $hash));
```

Since it by default uses `bcrypt`

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords